# Failed to lazily resolve the supplied JwtDecoder instance

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-oauth2

I am getting this strange exception from the Oauth2 resource server in spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server (version 3.10). Any clues on how to resolve this?

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderInitializationException: Failed to lazily resolve the supplied JwtDecoder instance
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.wrapException(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:53) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.lambda$new$0(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:39) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.util.function.SingletonSupplier.get(SingletonSupplier.java:97) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.decode(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:49) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:99) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://localhost:8080"
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfiguration(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:166) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfigurationForIssuerLocation(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:80) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.lambda$withIssuerLocation$2(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:223) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder.processor(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:386) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder$JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilder.build(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:402) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration$JwtDecoderConfiguration.lambda$jwtDecoderByIssuerUri$5(OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration.java:148) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.SupplierJwtDecoder.lambda$new$0(SupplierJwtDecoder.java:36) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:124) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1132) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1115) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:865) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:714) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfiguration(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:155) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

I tried configuring a custom RestTemplate along with a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter as shown below, but still the error is coming.

```
@Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate  restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();        

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));         
        messageConverters.add(converter);  
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters); 
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: Why did you think configuring a RestTemplate would solve your issue?

Comment: Did you solve this?  If so please post answer.